# How to place a # character in a message?

Tags: warnings, package-writing, strings

How can I place a `#` symbol inside of a `\PackageWarning` inside of a macro definition? I tried:

```
\PackageWarning{package}{# or \# or \string# or \hash}
```

but either `##` or `unknown` (for `\hash`) or `Illegal parameter number in definition of \reserved@a` resulted.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Actually `\string#` is the way to go, however you seem to use `\PackageWarning` as part of a macro definition so you have to double it: `\string##`.
The macro definition of `\reserved@a` might happen internally in a macro you are using. Some if-macros from the LaTeX core for example store both clauses in such temporary macros.

You could also define a macro for this character which then can be used in all `\PackageWarning`s and other messages independent if they are in a macro definition or not.

```
\edef\hashchar{\string#}
```

Then use `\hashchar` in the message. If you want a space behind it you need to use `\space` explicitly.

Comment: `\edef\hashchar{\string#}`

Comment: @egreg: Indeed! Sometimes I think to complicated, even if the simply solution is right before my nose :-)

Comment: @egreg: Works and has got the advantage to be usable inside and outside of another macro. +1 for this.

Comment: As a side note, for LaTeX3, we`ve gone for letting `\#` be that single hash character within messages. Same with a couple of standard special characters.